# Why aren't I picking up the exit status from my child process?

Tags: perl, posix, fork

I have a Perl program that I'm managing on that has the ability to fork off multiple processes (up to a specified limit), monitor them, and as they exit, fork off additional processes (once again, up to the limit), until the list of things to run is completed. It works fine, except for some reason it doesn't appear to be picking up the correct exit status from my child processes.

The code that doesn't work uses Perl's `fork()`, `waitpid()`, and the child processes use `POSIX::_exit()` to quit. Here's some excerpts of the relevant code:

**Forking code:**

```
# Initialize process if running in parallel mode
my $pid;
if ($options{'parallel'} > 0) {
    log_status("Waiting to fork test #".$curr_test{'id'}."...\n");

    # Here, wait for child processes to complete so we can fork off new ones without going over the specified limit
    while ( keys(%children) >= $options{'parallel'}) {
        my $kid = waitpid(-1, 0);
        my $kid_status = $?;

        if ($kid > 0) {
            log_status("Child process (PID ".$kid.", test ".$children{$kid}.") exited with status ".$kid_status.".\n");
            $error_status |= $kid_status;
            delete $children{$kid};
        }
    }

    $pid = fork();
    tdie("Unable to fork!\n") unless defined $pid;

    if ($pid != 0) {
        # I'm the parent
        $is_child = 0;
        log_status("Forked child process (PID ".$pid.").\n");

        $children{$pid} = $curr_test{'logstr'};

        next TEST_LOOP;
    }
    else {
        # I'm the child
        $is_child = 1;
        log_status("Starting test = ".$curr_test{'logstr'}."\n");
    }
}
```

**Exit child process code:**

```
### finish_child() ###
# Handles exiting the script, like the finish() function, but only when running as a child process in parallel mode.
# Parameters:
#   - The error code to exit with
###
sub finish_child( $ ) {
    my ($error_status) = @_;


    # If running in parallel mode, exit this fork
    if ($options{'parallel'} > 0) {
        log_status("Entering: ".Cwd::abs_path("..")."\n");
        chdir "..";
        log_status("Exiting with status: ".$error_status."\n");
        POSIX::_exit($error_status);
    }
}
```

**Here's where `finish_child()` is called in my example run:**

```
# If build failed, log status and gracefully clean up logfiles, then continue to next test in list.
if ($test_status > 0) {
    $email_subject = "Build failed!";
    log_status("Build of ".$testline." FAILED.\n");
    tlog(1, "Build of ".$testline." FAILED.\n");

    log_status("Entering: ".Cwd::abs_path("..")."\n");
    chdir "..";


    log_report(\%curr_test, $test_status);

    # Print out pass/fail status for each test as it completes
    $quietmode = $options{'quiet'}; # Backup quiet mode setting
    $options{'quiet'} = 0;

    if ($test_status == 0) {
        log_status("Test ".$testline." PASSED.\n");
        tlog(0, "Test ".$testline." PASSED.\n");
    }
    else {
        log_status("Test ".$testline." FAILED.\n");
        tlog(1, "Test ".$testline." FAILED.\n");
    }

    $options{'quiet'} = $quietmode;  # Restore quiet mode setting
    finish_logs();


    # Link logs to global area and rename if running multiple tests
    system("ln -sf ".$root_dir."/verify/".$curr_test{'id'}."/".$verify::logfile." ../".(($test_status > 0) ? "fail".$curr_test{'id'}.".log" : "pass".$curr_test{'id'}.".log" )) if (@tests > 1);


    if ($options{'parallel'} > 0 && $pid == 0) {
        # If we're in parallel mode and I'm a child process, I should exit, instead of continuing to loop.
        finish_child($test_status);
    }
    else {
        # If we're not in parallel mode, I should continue to loop.
        next TEST_LOOP;
    }
}
```

**Here's the behavior that I'm seeing according to the log from a run I did:**

```
<Parent> Waiting for all child processes to complete...
<Child> [PID 28657] Entering: <trimmed>
<Child> [PID 28657] Running user command: make --directory <trimmed> TARGET=build BUILD_DIR=<trimmed> RUN_DIR=<trimmed>            
<Child> [PID 28657] User command finished with return code: 512
<Child> [PID 28657] Build step finished with return code 512
<Child> [PID 28657] Entering: <trimmed>
<Child> [PID 28657] Build of rx::basic(1) FAILED.
<Child> [PID 28657] Entering: <trimmed>
<Child> [PID 28657] Test rx::basic(1) FAILED.
<Child> [PID 28657] Closing log file.
<Child> [PID 28657] Closing error log file.
<Child> [PID 28657] Entering: <trimmed>
<Parent> Child process (PID 28657, test rx::basic(1)) exited with status 0.
```

I have code that uses Perl IPCs to run commands (in lieu of the `system()` call, for more flexibility that picks up the exit code properly, which you can see in the "User command" lines from the log file.

What could I be doing wrong, here? Why wouldn't I be able to pick up the exit status from `$?` in this case? The examples I found online all seem to indicate that this should work fine.

For reference, I'm running `Perl v5.10.1`. This Perl tool is also open sourced on GitHub if you feel you need to look through the rest of the code: https://github.com/benrichards86/Verify/blob/master/verify.pl

Comment: Wheres the "Exiting with status:" line in the log?

Comment: @ikegami This I'm not sure. I didn't notice this earlier. It might be that it gets lost in the buffer. I'll debug this particular thing further and see what I find.

Comment: Ah, the version of the code that I ran didn't have that particular logging statement in `finish_child()`, which is why it didn't appear in the log snippet that I posted above. That was the only difference, though. Hence the discrepancy. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `$test_status` is 512, are you calling `POSIX::_exit(512)`? That is incorrect.
A child process should call `POSIX::_exit` with an operand in the range 0 to 255, and the Perl parent process that reaps that child will get `$?` set to *exit-status* `<< 8`.

`POSIX::_exit(512)` is equivalent to `POSIX::_exit(512 % 256)`, or `POSIX::_exit(0)`.

Comment: Oh, this is a very good point, and not something that I picked up on. I'll test a fix for this and see if it works!

Comment: I tried the fix and it worked! Marking this as the answer (though every answer here was helpful).

Comment: @ikegami I used your "do it like bash" suggestion and called: `POSIX::_exit(($error_status & 0x7F) ? ($error_status | 0x80) : ($error_status >> 8));`. Marked this as the answer because he got here first and was correct.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are doing what amounts to the following:

```
exit($?)
```

You mean to propagate the value the child passed to `exit`, but that's not what `$?` contains.

If the child was killed by a signal, `$? & 0x7F` contains the number of the signal that killed the process.

If the child wasn't killed by a signal, `$? & 0x7F` is zero, and `$? >> 8` contains a the value the process passed to `exit`.

So when the child does `exit(1)`, you do `exit(256)`, and that's out of range on Unix systems. The high bits are chopped off leaving you with zero (`256 & 0xFF = 0`).

---

I suggest that you do what `bash` does:

```
exit( ($? & 0x7F) ? ($? | 0x80) : ($? >> 8) );
```

When the child does `exit(1)`, this does `exit(1)`.

When the child is killed by, say, SIGTERM (15), this does `exit(128 + 15)`.

Comment: (I used `exit` in my examples, but everything I said also applies to `_exit`.)

Comment: Thanks! I used your "do what bash does" suggestion where I called `POSIX::_exit()`, which fixed the issue. I marked @mob's answer though, since he got here first. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that may be the explanation but what intrigues me is that your test output doesn't show the exit status that the child actually uses.  There's a log message in the code ("Exiting with status:...") but no corresponding line in the output.

So we can't really tell if anything's going wrong in this part of your code.

I first thought the use of POSIX::_exit might explain the logging problem (it would prevent final buffers from being flushed), but looking at your code again I see that you've turned logging off before calling finish_child.

I'd recommend as a first step that you get the logging working right so that you can tell where the problem is.  Why not move the log close and logfile renaming logic into the finish child routine as the last thing done before exiting?

As for the exit status problem, I see three possible explanations, all in the code for the child process:

- the child isn't actually exiting through function finish_child
- the non-zero status you think is being passed to finish_child and then to exit actually isn't being passed
- as suggested above, your exit status is > 255

Is the any particular reason why you're using POSIX::_exit() instead of exit() and waitpid(-1) instead of wait()?

Comment: I've been in a process of refactoring the code quite a bit. This mostly centered around the parsing/indexing but the main flow of the script could probably use a rework too, which would end up including the logging. I wouldn't be surprised if there was some logging bugs in there! :)

Comment: `_exit` doesn't call destructors and END blocks meant to be executed in the parent. For example, if you have a database handle in the parent, calling `exit` in the child will close it, but `_exit` will leave the parent unaffected.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, this is why I used it. I believe I tried `exit()` at first and ran into that very problem (stale filehandles, for one).

Comment: If you want your END blocks to do different things depending on whether you're the child or not, use the global "$is_child" variable which you set as the first thing done when entering the child code.  That way you can use the standard exit() function, which means you won't have to worry about any side-effects from using non-core functions.

Comment: @VolDeNuit I may take a look. I realized yesterday that I could probably make use of that variable in more places than current. As I said, I'm reworking a lot of the code, so that might be something I'll look into.