# Resolving Perls "$?" return code: Why is it different from Hana sql error code ??

Tags: perl, debugging, error-code, hana, backticks

I have written a perl script that connects to hdbsql a commandline tool on SAP HANA. Hdbsql to SAP Hana is what sqlplus is to Oracle.

I am using backtick to fire a sql query on hdbsql and i am capturing the result of the query in an array. Following is the piece of code that performs this operation:

```
my $sql_statement = 'SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE  
                     some_condition';

my $hdb_sql = "/PROGRA~1/sap/hdbclient/hdbsql.exe";

my $connection = "-i 11 -n 100.450.10.20:31115 -u myUser -p myPwd -j -F   
                  \"|\"";

my @queryResults = `$hdb_sql $connection $sql_statement`;
```

Here is where i am facing issues. When the query executes successfully the hdbsql return code is 0 and the return code stored in perl variable "$?" is also zero.But in cases of error this is what i have observed:

When the query has some syntax issues i get the following is the error message:

```
* 257: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "SELECTS": line 1 col 1 (at 
pos 1) SQLSTATE: HY000
```

We see that the Hana sql error code is 257 from the above message.
But if i printout the perl variable "$?". It gives 256 as the error/return code.

Similarly,

- For invalid column name the hana sql error code is 260 but the perl return 
  code is 1024.
- For missing aggregation or grouping the hana sql error code is 276 but the 
  perl return code is 5120.
- For wrong number of arguments in a function the hana sql error code is 316 
  but the perl return code is 15360.
- For invalid table name the hana sql error code is 259 but the perl return 
  code is 768.

and so on...

**Why is it that the error codes that "$?" give are different from the actual hana sql return codes? In my script i want to print out the actual hana error code.How do i do it in perl. Is there a mathematical relation between the two codes**

I have to state this that i am keen on using backtics. I dont want to switch to 
system() , perl pipe , use perl DBI or any other module to fire the hdbsql query.

I have come across some similar questions asked in this forum but for my case they have been of very little help.

I appreciate your comments/answers. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640737/why-arent-i-picking-up-the-exit-status-from-my-child-process/18641283#18641283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` is usually a multiple of 256. See [`perldoc -f system`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?system) (though this applies to assignment of `$?` after backticks and `wait` as well).

The `exit` (and `POSIX::_exit`) functions expect input on the range 0 to 255 -- this is an operating system convention, not a limitation of Perl. If you pass an argument outside that range, Perl or the operating system will treat it as if you called `exit($arg % 256)`.

So I think what is happening is that hana sql makes the system call to `exit` with the sql error code. This error code is typically greater than 255, so the exit code that gets propogated back to the operating system is `hana error code % 256`.

When Perl receives this error code and assigns a value to `$?`, it multiplies that value by 256 (as described in `perldoc -f system`), so the relationship between the hana sql code and `$?` is probably something like:

```
 $? = (<hana-sql-code> % 256) * 256
```

or more pedantically

```
 $? = (<hana-sql-code> & 255) << 8
```

Comment: hi "mob" and "ikegami" thank you!!! I get why the two codes are different. if i understood you right , if i have value of "$?" i can't get the original hana error code from it. Right ??

Comment: Not right. Original error code is `$? / 256 + 256` (assuming the hana code is always in the range 257-511)

Comment: Well the hana sql error codes range from 1 to  4105 and its not continuous.

Comment: Then at least you can narrow it down. If `$?` is 768 (`3<<8`), then the hana code is one of 3, 259, 515, 771, 1027, ..., 3587, or 3843.

Comment: Sure but the idea here is to resolve the error code so that we exactly know what the issue is . That way it makes debugging easier.

Comment: If that's the idea, then save the standard error stream of `hbdsql` and read it.

Comment: yupp!! That's an option.

Comment: Wondering If there is a way in perl to capture both output and error (in case of failure) in the same scalar or even 2 different scalars.